# All OLS assumptions not satisfied

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, linear

I sorted some portfolios using the constituents of the S&P500 and then estimate the linear multi factor models. Now, based on my first criterion I constructed 3 portfolios where all of them had good results regarding the diagnostic tests.
However, also constructing 3 different portfolios based on another criterion leads to clear rejection of normality, homoskedasticity and I also find evidence for autocorrelation (for all three portfolios).

Is it a problem to just use robust standard errors or is there some driver of these results? I am particularly unsure, because the other criteria give such good results although both are based on the S&P500.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to learn from your regression?

Comment: Thank you! 
I want to estimate the capital asset pricing model and see if the portfolios sorted on these criteria have a positive alpha (i.e. if there is a significant intercept).

Comment: The CAPM is a single factor model, so I am a bit unclear what you are wanting to do.